# unable to read data from decoded token jwt verify

Tags: jwt, nestjs

```
jwt.verify(token,process.env.SECRETKEY, function(err,decodedToken){

      console.log(decodedToken);

    })
Console output
{ email: 'm.blal@gmail.com', iat: 1601341321 }
```

how can I read the value of email from decoded token?

Answer (score 0):

Attach the email to the request, then you can access that value from the controller

```js
jwt.verify(token,process.env.SECRETKEY, function(err,decodedToken){
      if(err) throw new ForbiddenException('Invalid token'); 
      req.user = decodedToken //Attach token payload to request
    })
```

You can use that value later on the controller using req.user or creating a decorator (I prefer this).